# martingale difference sequence

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am solving an exercise where I am using a martingale difference sequence, so here is my doubt. $\varepsilon_t$ is a stationary and ergodic martingale difference sequence. I get to one point where I have $-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_T +\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_0$ where T is the maximum value of t and 0 is the minimum. Is the result of the difference 0? If yes, could you please explain why?

Comment: I would say it is not. What it is 0 is the expected value of that difference.